# Laravel won't to set localize in Kernel file - it works only when I set in routes/api.php

Tags: php, laravel, localization

In Laravel I added, according to the solution from site: [set Locale in Laravel](https://mydnic.be/post/laravel-5-and-his-fcking-non-persistent-app-setlocale)

SetLocale.php file in `app/Http/Middleware`
In this file I set localization:

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Middleware;
    
    use Closure;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
    
    class SetLocale
    {
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            App::setLocale('fr');
            
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

And Laravel doesn't call above function. In my app all time I have set en language. In `Kernel.php` file I added both to web and api groups:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class,
        EncryptCookies::class,
        AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        StartSession::class,
        ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class,
```

But method handle from `SetLocale` isn't called.

It works when I add to the `routes/api.php` file this line:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

app()->setLocale('fr');
Route::get('/', function ()
{
    return 'Hello API';
});
```

---

This is my `config/app.php` file where locale is set to fr:

```
'locale' => 'fr',
'fallback_locale' => 'fr',
```

---

I'm checking that in controller:

```
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function store (Request $request)
    {
       return response()->json([ 'message' => __('auth.testmessage') . ' ' . app()->getLocale() ]);
```

And when I call request to this method I get:

```
{"message":"test message2 en"}
```

But when I set in `api.php` file I get `... test message2 fr`

Comment: if you always want that locale why not just set it in your config?

Comment: Doesn't matter it isn't work in both of the cases

Comment: did you cache your configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the app locale you just have to modify the `config/app.php` file.

This file contains an `array`, change the value from key `locale` to the locale you want like so:

```php
'locale' => 'fr',
```

You may need to clear the config cache after that:

Run this command in your project folder `php artisan config:cache`

---

The site you showed is just showing how to change your application locale config at runtime when you have a system with multiple languages and you want to provide this feature, changing the language from any page.

Comment: I set in config/app.php but it doesn't help

Comment: What changes are you tracking to see if it worked or not? PHP Time locale? Form error messages? ...?

Comment: I added response in my post

Comment: @Robert try to clear the config cache from your application, in your project folder use this command: `php artisan config:cache`